# Какую Ubuntu лучше всего поставить на ноутбук?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amd, radeon

Решил перескочить на Ubuntu, до этого пользовался Windows.
Вчера поставил 16.04 LTS не порадовало, лагало страшно, возможно криво поставил.
Ноутбук Lenovo g575

Характеристики:

```
AMD Dual-Core E-450 (1.65 ГГц) / RAM 4 ГБ / HDD 500 ГБ / AMD Radeon HD 6320
```

Comment: В чем проявлялись "лаги"? Что значит, криво поставили, если вы, наверняка, пользовались графическим установщиком?

Comment: Лаги скорее всего проявлялись из-за Radeon'a. Линь плохо дружит с ними. Ставьте какую-нибудь малоресурсную оболочку типо XFCE.

Comment: @mkkik при открытии каких либо приложении долго думает, а про видео в ютубе вообще молчу, максимум, что получилось смотреть это в 240p

Comment: @k0mar можно попробовать 14.04 LTS с 3.x ядром. Там старые радеоны поддерживаются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую присмотреться к таким дистрибутивам, как: **Arch Linux**, **Puppy Linux**, **Trisquel Mini**, **Ubuntu MATE + Linux Mint MATE**, **Lubuntu**, **Debian**, **Porteus**.

Все они легковесные дистрибутивы Linux. Пойдет на вашей машине на ура.

Comment: Арч для новичка самое то, конечно. Как и остальная маргинальщина, о которой половина линуксоидов то не слышала. Пусть сразу слаку ставит, ага. :)

Comment: У арча отличное сообщество. Помогут.

Comment: Сначала попробую поставить, как подсказали, оболочку XFCE, не поможет бахну дебиан, спасибо)

Comment: Я бы тоже для начала выбрал Arche. Arch Linux made easy :)

Comment: А я всем рекомендую Windows

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте поставить в уже установленном Ubuntu оболочку XFCE. Для этого достаточно выполнить команды:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install xfce4-goodies
```

Или с нуля можно поставить Xubuntu, но, имхо, особого смысла в этом нет.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую)

Comment: Ага. И при этом пытаться запускать всё те же программки требующие прожорливых кде, гнома, юнити вместе взятых.